# how to replace multiple lines using bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, replace, line

I have a file with thousands of lines. I'm looking for help to modify multiple lines which i were to choose.

```
Package: com.xyz.abc
Version: 1.0
Filename: ./debs/abc.deb

Package: com.xyz.def
Version: 1.0.0-1
Filename: ./debs/def.deb
```

I need a bash command to detect "Filename" then change them to something like this:

```
Package: com.xyz.abc
Version: 1.0
Filename: ./debs/download.php?p=abc

Package: com.xyz.def
Version: 1.0.0-1
Filename: ./debs/download.php?p=def
```

And it will loop till all "Filename" have been changed.

Comment: You should first show what you have tried, what code you have written, and only then ask for assistance. Do you want a fish or be able to fish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a job for `sed`! From the [GNU sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) homepage:

> Sed is typically used for extracting part of a file using pattern matching or substituting multiple occurrences of a string within a file.

Here is how you could do it:

```
sed '/^Filename:/s!\(./debs/\)\(.*\).deb!\1download.php?p=\2!' /path/to/input > /path/to/output
```

Where:

- `/^Filename:/` looks for lines starting with (`^`) the text 'Filename:'
- `s!search!replace!` replaces 'search' with 'replace' where 'search' is a regular expression
- `\1` is the string captured by the first matching group "`\(...\)`"
- `\2` is the string captured by the second matching group "`\(...\)`"

Demonstration:

```
$ echo 'Package: com.xyz.abc
Version: 1.0
Filename: ./debs/abc.deb

Package: com.xyz.def
Version: 1.0.0-1
Filename: ./debs/def.deb' | sed '/^Filename:/s!\(./debs/\)\(.*\).deb!\1download.php?p=\2!' 
Package: com.xyz.abc
Version: 1.0
Filename: ./debs/download.php?p=abc

Package: com.xyz.def
Version: 1.0.0-1
Filename: ./debs/download.php?p=def
```

For tweaking this and for writing your own `sed` scripts, please consult the [online documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/).

Comment: @downvoter: Why? If there is something wrong with my answer, please point it out.

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution:

```
perl -pi -e '/^Filename:/ and s,debs/([^.]+)\.deb\s*$,debs/download.php?p=$1,' thefile
```

First try it by not putting it the `i` option and pipe with `less`. Then re-add the `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Not in bash itself, but:

```
sed 's#Filename: \./debs/\(.*\)\.deb#Filename: ./debs/download.php?p=\1#' < the_file
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a tool called `sed`:

```
sed -e "s|^(Filename: ./debs/)(.+).deb|\1download.php?p=\2|" < yourfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are improved answers with `awk` and `sed`.

Unlike the other answers, these work independent of what the 'Filename:' path is.  That is to say, if you change './debs/' to './myDebs/' it will still work.  All they require is that '.deb' file is at the end of the path

#### Sed

```
sed '/Filename:/s|^\(.*/\)\([^\.]*\)\..*$|\1download.php?p=\2|' ./infile
```

#### awk

```
awk -F'/' '/Filename:/{split($NF,a,".");$NF="download.php?p=" a[1]}1' OFS='/' ./infile
```

#### Input

```
$ cat ./infile
Package: com.xyz.abc
Version: 1.0
Filename: ./debs/abc.deb

Package: com.xyz.def
Version: 1.0.0-1
Filename: ./MyDebs/def.deb
```

#### sed Output

```
$ sed '/Filename:/s|^\(.*/\)\([^\.]*\)\..*$|\1download.php?p=\2|' ./infile
Package: com.xyz.abc
Version: 1.0
Filename: ./debs/download.php?p=abc

Package: com.xyz.def
Version: 1.0.0-1
Filename: ./MyDebs/download.php?p=def
```

#### awk Output

```
$ awk -F'/' '/Filename:/{split($NF,a,".");$NF="download.php?p=" a[1]}1' OFS='/' ./infile
Package: com.xyz.abc
Version: 1.0
Filename: ./debs/download.php?p=abc

Package: com.xyz.def
Version: 1.0.0-1
Filename: ./MyDebs/download.php?p=def
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed '/^Filename:/s/\([^/]*\)\.[^.]*$/download.php?p=\1/' file
```